# Nested for-loop that is only O(n)

Tags: c, recursion

How would I write a function that contains a nested for-loop but is only order(n)?  Im not sure if i need to use recursion or not.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? A small code sample would help.

Comment: what do you want to do?

Answer (score 5):

If the inner for loop is a constant number of loops rather than a variable number of loops, while the outer loop is a variable number of loops (or vice versa) the time complexity is O(n*C) where C is a constant, which just means O(n) (since big O notation is only concerned with growing factors).